Besov spaces containing piecewise linear functions
Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, non-empty, regular open domain in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Let $1\le p,q\le \infty$ and $s>0$.  Let $\mathcal{B}_{p,q}^s(\Omega)$ be the Besov space on $\Omega$ corresponding to these parameters, see eg Triebel's book [1].
Let $PW(\Omega)$ denote the set of functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which are the restriction of piecewise linear functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ (with finitely many pieces).

My question is, what values of $p,q,s$ are such that $PW(\Omega)\subset \mathcal{B}_{p,q}^s(\Omega)$?  Clearly, when $p=q=\infty$ and $s=1$ then $\mathcal{B}_{p,q}^s(\Omega)$ is the set of Lipschitz functions on $\Omega$, so $PW(\Omega)\subset \mathcal{B}_{\infty,\infty}^1(\Omega)$; however, what inclusions are known to hold in general?
[1] Triebel, H. (2008). Function spaces and wavelets on domains (No. 7). European Mathematical Society.

I assume you piece-wise linear functions are at least continuous, sicne you seem to assume they are Lipschitz. Therefore, it should belong to all Besov spaces $\mathrm{B}^{s}_{p,q}(\Omega)$, $p,q\in[1,+\infty]$, $s<1+1/p$.
The idea is that piece-wise constant functions, which are derivatives of your considered functions, belong to Besov spaces for $s<1/p$.

@ToGle Do you have a reference to this?

This follows from the fundamental multiplier theorem saying that the characteristic function of the half-plane yields a bounded multiplier on Besov spaces ${\mathrm{B}}^s_{p,q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ provided $p,q\in[1,+\infty]$ and $s\in(-1+\tfrac{1}{p},\tfrac{1}{p})$.

Can be found for example in the first by book by Triebel Theory of Function spaces

@ToGle Amazing; thanks a lot :)
